# can we use alb behind new nlb target group, so that we can use all features of REST type api gateway like Cognito, Xray

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

in my current existed environment we have aws alb with backend APIs in ECS fargate, now I want to integrate aws API gateway and Cognito with alb. but as per AWS docs, we can only use rest API type API gateway for Cognito integration, but again as per AWS docs with rest API gateway type we can't use alb and we can only use nlb but my APIs are configured with path-based routing in alb

1. if I replace my alb with nlb how can I achieve my path-based routing for the backend API's and is there any other way that I can use to configure Cognito, rest API and loadbalcners
2. as I said can I use alb behind new nlb target group

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact use Cognito to secure HTTP APIs in API Gateway by configuring a [JWT authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html)

This example [CloudFormation template](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-api-gateway-developer-guide/blob/2d3acfd53f23c8148f0ba1861b7a71523d9c118e/cloudformation-templates/HTTP/http-with-jwt-auth.yaml) will help you get it configured.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Gillis can I put alb behind the new nlb target group to use Rest type gateway